# Pass an html ngModel value to service angular

Tags: angular, combobox, kendo-ui

I want to pass an html ngModel value  <kendo-dropdownlist style=" width: 92%;" [data]="year" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear"> which is located on Combocomponent.html, to a service which is called Home.service.ts.

Inside the service I have this code:

```
  configUrl1 = 'https://localhost:44361/api/Active_Serviced_Outlets?Year=2021&quarter=1&month=1';
  getMethod1() {
    
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl1);
  }
```

I want to dynamically pass the [(ngModel)]="selectedYear" value to selected Year so every time the user inputs an year.

ComboComponent.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">

    <p> &nbsp; &nbsp;<b>Year </b></p>

    <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="year" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear"></kendo-dropdownlist>
  </div>
  <div class="column">

    <p> &nbsp; &nbsp;<b>Month</b></p>
    <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="Month" [(ngModel)]="selectedMonth"> </kendo-dropdownlist>
  </div>
  <div class="columnA">
    <p> &nbsp; &nbsp;<b>Quarter</b></p>
    <kendo-dropdownlist style=" width: 92%;" [data]="Quarter" [(ngModel)]="selectedQuarter"> </kendo-dropdownlist>
  </div>

   
</div>
<br />
<!--<div class="example-config">
  &nbsp; &nbsp;Selected Values: {{selectedYear}} &nbsp; &nbsp; {{selectedMonth}} &nbsp; &nbsp; {{selectedQuarter}}
</div>-->
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to a that `selectedYear` to your service.

**service.ts**

```
public selectedYear = 1900; // You can default to any year or make it null.


getWhatever() {
  
  const url = `https://example/api/whatever?Year=${selectedYear}`
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Then in the component, wrap the `selectedYear` in a getter and setter.

**component.ts**

```
public get selectedYear() {
  return this._service.selectedYear;
}
public set selectedYear(year: number) {
  this._service.selectedYear = year;
}

constructor(
  private readonly _service: myService
){}
```

Finally, use the getter/setter in the HMTL.
**component.html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedYear">
...
</select>
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpakhk).

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: @PiumiRathnayaka: I updated my answer to include the demo.